# Не получается сохранить данные в массив через axios

Tags: массивы, reactjs, объекты, axios, promise

Не могу обработать сохранённый массив `dataBase`

```
const dataBase = []

axios('https://dpg.gg/test/calendar.json')
  .then((res) => {
    dataBase.push(res.data);
  })
console.log(dataBase);
```